# For $B _{n-1 } $ open, $\bar B _n \setminus B _{n-1 } $ is a closed set.

Tags: general-topology

Let $B _n $ be an increasing sequence of open sets in some measure space $X $. Is it true that $\bar B _n \setminus B _{n-1 } $ is a closed set.

Can I reason as follows? In the subspace $\bar B _n $ of $X $, $B _{n-1 } $ is an open set and thus its complement $\bar B _n \setminus B _{n-1 } $ is a closed set. Then this implies that $\bar B _n \setminus B _{n-1 } $ is a closed set in $X $.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Being closed in the subspace does not imply closedness in the space $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bar{B}_{n} \setminus B_{n-1} = \bar{B}_{n} \cap A_{n-1}$, where $A_{n-1}$ is the complement of the open set $B_{n}$ in $X$, therefore $A_{n-1}$ is closed. The intersection of 2 closed sets being closed, $\bar{B}_{n} \setminus B_{n-1}$ is closed in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

$\bar{B}_n \setminus B_{n-1} = \left(X\setminus B_{n-1}\right) \cap \bar{B}_{n}$ is a finite intersection of closed sets, which is closed.

Comment: Ok, simple. But would my reasoning still be correct though?

Comment: No, closed in the subspace does not mean closed in $X$.

Comment: no, as mentionned by user1123. Closedness in a subspace of $X$ with induced topology does NOT imply closedness in $X$. Let me give you an example :  $]0,1[$ is closed in the subset $]0,1[$ of $X = \mathbb{R}$ (with the classical topology), but is certainly not closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed in the topology it inherits from $\mathbb{R}$, but it is certainly not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, because its set of limit points is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is wrong, the set of limit points of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, and not $\mathbb{I}$. But the argument still holds.

Comment: @HerbertQuain oh yeah whoops, correct. edited